# repeated divs loaded by angular could have different contents, how can I make them have automatically adjusted heights?

Tags: css, angularjs

My nodejs/angularjs application auto-loads via the angular_controller and mongodb a bunch of divs.

HTML:

```
<div class="sunti_contain" ng-repeat="sunti in suntis track by $index">
                <div class="individual_sunti">
                    <!--needs a unique div#id via angularz-->
                    <div class="sunti_content">{{sunti.content || 'content loading...'}}</div>
                    <div class="sunti_tags">{{sunti.tags || 'tags'}}</div>
                    <div class="sunti_author">{{sunti.author || 'author-placeholder'}}</div>
                    <div class="sunti_shortid">{{sunti.shortid}}</div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I have them all sharing the same class:

```
.individual_sunti {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    border: 0.05em solid orange;
    width: 30em;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -15em;
    min-height: 3em;
    height: auto
    display: block;
    background-color: hsla(360, 100%, 100%, 0.95);
}

.sunti_contain {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}

.sunti_content {
    height: auto;
    overflow: auto;

}


.sunti_tags {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: hsla(100, 100%, 50%, 0.5);
}

.sunti_author {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: hsla(130, 100%, 50%, 0.5);
}

.sunti_shortid {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    bottom: 1em;
    right: 0;
}
```

and Angular populates them with the model binding like so, when someone posts one using a form on the page:

```
$scope.submit_sunti = function() {
    socket.emit('post_new_sunti', {
        content: $scope.sunti.content,
        tags: $scope.sunti.tags,
        ancestor: $scope.sunti.ancestor
    })
    $scope.sunti.content = ""
    $scope.sunti.tags = ""
    $scope.sunti.ancestor = ""
}
```

Basically, they all end up having the same height no matter what.  Someone suggested flexbox, I'm not familiar with it enough yet to make sense of how it would work here.  Angular populates the HTML with the line

`ng-repeat="sunti in suntis"`  with the optional `track by $index` in case two have the same exact contents (unlikely but possible)

```
.sunti_content
```

grows because it clearly contains the text, but does this mean I need unique div ids (like in my html-comment-to-myslf-above) to make certain that every generated sunti div is its own proper height?

How can I have the angular-populated-divs scale to fit their content?  Is it possible to "fix it" via CSS alone?

Thanks

Comment: use css flexbox. Provide [mcve]

Comment: by automatically adjust heights, do you mean all divs will be the same height too?

Comment: @JoeyWood different heights for different content-amounts is what is desired

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You hard code the height to be

```
height: 12em
```

This means your divs won't automatically size and will just default to that height

Comment: Whats the css for your other classes?

Comment: sir you are a king! I had a double definition for `.sunti_contain` where it had some absolute positioning.  Thanks for making me double check that.  Way to go.